# C++ template implementation to store 2D nested vector data continuously?

Tags: c++, vector, nested, stl, 2d

Storing a two-dimensional grid as `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` is rather inefficient because each of the inner vectors contains separately allocated heap memory.
I am seeking a template implementation to let me do the things like:

```
nested_vector<double, 2> nv;
nv.push_back({0, 1, 2});   // row1
nv.push_back({3, 4});      // row2
nv.push_back({5, 6, 7, 8});// row3
```

Ideal storage in memory:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|     row 1     |     row 2     |     row 3     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

instead of

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>>  v = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
```

```
--------------
|     row 1     |
-------------
|     row 2     |
-------------
|     row 3     |
--------------
```

Is there any template implementation to do this?
Any tips will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a two dimensional grid as your rows have different sizes. If it was pure `n × m` then there are various matrix implementations for it. Otherwise there are multiple solutions each with its own set of ups and downs.

Comment: what's happen when row2 expanding ? if size of your 2d array is const I think std::array<std::array, n> is match for your issue where n is longest in rows

Comment: if rows have different size then you need dynamically sized rows and a `std::vector<std::vector>>` is just fine. A `std::vector<std::vector>>` is not the best when rows have fixed size

Comment: suppose you call `nv.resize(3)` and then assign the rows in reverse order. How do you know how much size the first 2 will need when they can be different number of elements?

Comment: In general if you want predictable memory layout you will need to know the size of your data-structure at compile time. (And the you can use std::array of std::array). Another way is to make a complex datastructure yourself that will keep track of sizes of rows and can move data forward and backward in memory when rows resize, what you gain in memory you lose in performance (which is a common design tradeoff)

Comment: Yes, I am adware of the points you mentioned above. This 1d flat data structure is exactly what I want.

Comment: Fixed: *aware of

Comment: Can you resize inner vector?

Comment: Yes, the inner vector should be resizable.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a template to pass different number of parameters to a function. You can use a initializer list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct foo {
    std::vector<int> data;
    void add(std::initializer_list<int> a){
        std::copy(a.begin(),a.end(),std::back_inserter(data));
    }
};

int main() 
{
    foo f;
    f.add({1,2,3});
    f.add({1,2,3,4});
    f.add({1,2,3,4,5});
    for (const auto& e : f.data) std::cout << e;
}
```

However, as the "rows" are of different size, you will need to do more to know where a row ends. If row sizes are dynamic and can change during runtime then a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is probably just fine. Using a flat 1d container and resizing rows would require to move around elements very often. Also you cannot `resize` when you do not know the size of a row before hand. Things are different when the size of the rows is fixed, then you'd need to do the index transformations and place added elements at the right position.

Comment: with your solution, i think `struct foo` need save more information to accessing via index correctly like`f.at(row, col);` . OP may need to recover the original matrix .

Comment: I do want a flat 1d container that each row could be dynamically resized.

Comment: @SzuLi ok then the code in this answer is a start. Though I doubt that resizing a flat array is more performant than a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: @long.kl thats what I wrote

Comment: Yes the resizing would be slower, but iterations would be faster, that’s what I expected.

Comment: @SzuLi are you looking for an existing implenetation? Thats offtopic. I only tried to show how you can make the code in your question work

Comment: I see, it would be helpful that there is an existing implementation for me to dig into.

Comment: @SzuLi you just need to store the row offsets and add the 2d <-> 1d index mapping.

Comment: @SzuLi its not complicated code but a whole lot of tradeoffs to be made, hence there is not much more I can show. For example you can either store size of rows, or the 1d index of their start. The first makes the index transformation slightly more expensize while the second makes resizing more expensive